# asp.net mvc 3 razor Two controllers in one view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Want to use two models in one view. I have two controllers one for current user

```
 public class ProfileModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public decimal Balance { get; set; }
        public decimal RankNumber { get; set; }
        public decimal RankID { get; set; }
        public string PorfileImgUrl { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }
```

and second for firends

```
 public class FriendsModel 
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ProfilePictureUrl { get; set; }
        public string RankName { get; set; }
        public decimal RankNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

Profile model contains always one item and Friend model contains list

I have made new model which contains both models :

```
public class FullProfileModel 
    {
        public ProfileModel ProfileModel { get; set; }
        public FriendsModel FriendModel { get; set; }
    }
```

I tried to fill FullProfile model like this

```
List<FriendsModel> fmList = GetFriendsData(_UserID);

            FullProfileModel fullModel = new FullProfileModel();

            fullModel.ProfileModel = pm;
            fullModel.FriendModel = fmList.ToList();
```

but visual studio gives an error on .ToList()

error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<NGGmvc.Models.FriendsModel>' to 'NGGmvc.Models.FriendsModel'
```

Please advice me something how i can show two models in single view.

p.s. im using mvc3 razor view engine

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set a property of type FriendsModel with a value of List.

```
 public FriendsModel FriendModel { get; set; }
```

Change to:

```
public class FullProfileModel 
    {
        public ProfileModel ProfileModel { get; set; }
        public IList<FriendsModel> FriendModel { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct your ViewModel

```
public class FullProfileModel 
    {
        public ProfileModel ProfileModel { get; set; }
        public IList<FriendsModel> FriendModels { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need collection

```
public class FullProfileModel 
{
    public ProfileModel ProfileModel { get; set; }
    public List<FriendsModel> FriendModels { get; set; }
}
```